# Windows SDK path common to Windows XP (32-bit) and Windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: path, winapi, program-files

I'm using a tool from the Windows SDK in my Visual Studio project. I need to support both Windows XP (32-bit) and Windows 7 (64-bit) development environments.

The Windows SDK gets installed under `Program Files` in both OSes. This is the problem!

I can't figure out what environment variable to use for the path. From a 32-bit process like Visual Studio the environment variables that map to `Program Files` are:

- Windows XP (32-bit): `%ProgramFiles%`
- Windows 7 (64-bit): `%ProgramW6432%`

These are different, so how can I tell Visual Studio what the path is to the Windows SDK?

I'd like to avoid any special configuration, like hardcoding the path or adding more environment variables.

Comment: AFAIK I can't install a 32-bit version of the Windows SDK on a Windows 7 (64-bit) machine. The x86 ISO doesn't work on Windows 7 (64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to specify the path as `%SystemDrive%\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0`, but I don't like it!